# Raspberry Pi is not able to subscribe to ros topic published from base PC but vice-verse is working?

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-16.04, raspberry-pi3, ubuntu-18.04, ros

I am using the ubiquityrobotics Raspberry Pi [image](https://downloads.ubiquityrobotics.com/pi.html) for the RPi 3B+, which is Ubuntu Xenial and ROS Kinetic. My base computer is running Ubuntu 18.04 and has ROS Melodic installed.
I created `subo_base` workspace in the base PC and `subo_rpi` workspace in the RPi (assessing the RPi via ssh). 
Then I created a package in both the base PC and RPi and added the Publisher and Subscriber (http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28python%29) files in each of the packages.
When I run the publisher from the RPi, the base PC is able to subscribe but when I publish from the base PC, the RPi does not show any output and remains stuck (even though the Topic is visible on RPi using `rostopic list`).

[Base PC is able to subscribe to RPi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKSG9.png)

[RPi unable to subscribe to topic from PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12rMh.png)

Some of the code is used in base PC

```
aakash@aakash:~$ mkdir -p ~/subo_base/src
aakash@aakash:~$ cd ~/subo_base/
aakash@aakash:~/subo_base$ catkin_make
aakash@aakash:~/subo_base$ source devel/setup.bash
aakash@aakash:~/subo_base$ echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
aakash@aakash:~/subo_base$ cd ~/subo_base/src/
aakash@aakash:~/subo_base/src$ catkin_create_pkg motion_plan std_msgs rospy roscpp
```

To connect to RPi

```
aakash@aakash:~/subo_base/src/motion_plan/scripts$ export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://ubiquityrobot.local:11311
aakash@aakash:~/subo_base/src/motion_plan/scripts$ export ROS_IP='hostname -I'
```

Further, I am able to transfer files from and to the base PC via ssh `scp` so I guess netwkr might not be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is most likely the hostname resolution and/or ROS  network variable configuration.

I dislike using the hostname in the variables, so I will give the examples using just IPs.

Also the `'hostname -I'` is definitely not suitable for setting your ROS_IP variable in all cases. So that might also be one source of your problem.

From hostname man page

> -I, --all-ip-addresses>
>
> Display all network  addresses  of  the  host. This    option   enumerates   all   configured addresses on all network interfaces. The loop‐back  interface  and IPv6 link-local addresses are  omitted.  Contrary  to  option  -i,  this option  does not depend on name resolution. Do not make any assumptions about  the  order  of
>   the output.

You will want to use whatever specific ip address you need, so just use that or find a better way to determine which ip to set. `echo $ROS_IP` or `printenv | grep ROS` will tell you what your variables are currently set to so you can verify it is set correctly.

For minimal proof that things are working you could try the following:

Lets say your RPi ip is 192.168.0.2 and PC ip is 192.168.0.3

You will need to decide which machine will be the master, for this example I will assume the PC will be the master.

> In a terminal on the PC run the following commands:
>
> > `roscore`
>
> in a different terminal run (this is used instead of the subscriber/publisher node to test if things work)
>
> > `rostopic pub /test/topic std_msgs/String 'Hello World from PC' -r 1`
>
> Now on the SSH terminal on the RPi run:
>
> > `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.0.3:11311 && export ROS_IP=192.168.0.2`
>
> now you should be able to echo the topic published on the PC from the SSH window.
>
> > `rostopic echo /test/topic`
>
> ctrl+c out of the echo and you can try publishing some message on the RPi like:
>
> > `rostopic pub /test2/topic std_msgs/String 'Hello World from RPi' -r 1`
>
> Now open a new terminal on the PC and try to echo the topic from RPi, any terminal sourced with the ROS installspace, usually `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`, should work:
>
> > `rostopic echo /test2/topic`

[ROS wiki page on running ROS on multiple machines](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/MultipleMachines)

[ROS answer regarding setting up multiple machines](https://answers.ros.org/question/297597/publishersubscriber-error-with-cmd_vel/#297649)

Comment: It worked after I set the `ROS_IP` explicitly in the RPi (master). Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

### ROS1

Machine1 [MASTER]:

- Will run `roscore`, but don't run it yet till configurations are done.
- Has an IP of `192.168.1.10`.

1- Run the following in the terminal:

1.1- `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.10:11311`.

1.2- `export ROS_IP=192.168.1.10`.

2- Now, run `roscore`.

Machine2 [SLAVE]

- Will NOT run `roscore`.
- Has and IP `192.168.1.15`.

1- Run the following in the terminal:

1.1- `export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.1.10:11311`.

1.2- `export ROS_IP=192.168.1.15`.

2- Now, you are connected to the Master.

---

### ROS2

ROS2 will populate the information on the LAN out of the box without any configuration.